# Is there a difference between running a python script via a relative and an absolute path?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm getting a weird error that depends on whether I run the same Python 2.7 script from a relative or absolute path.

In other words, if I have a python script located in `c:\tmp\git\enigma\blah.py` and my current directory is in `c:\tmp\otherdir`, this works:

```
python ..\git\enigma\blah.py some_args
```

but this fails:

```
python c:\tmp\git\enigma\blah.py some_args
```

The script does run in both cases, and uses subprocess.Popen in both cases to call another program, changing the directory to what I think is the same place, but something fails if I use an absolute path to invoke Python.

I'm double checking the script --- I didn't write it --- to see if it relies on the current working directory anywhere, but it's suspicious that the two cases are different.

Aside from looking if the program uses `sys.argv[0]`, can anyone suggest things to look at which might depend on this difference?

---

OK, so it looks like the issue is the command this script is executing (yarn) seems to depend on case-sensitivity of the drive letter in Windows.

I am located in `C:\tmp\git\enigma`. If I use a relative path, it picks up the correct drive letter. If I use an absolute path `python c:\tmp\git\enigma\blah.py`, then the spawned process seems to get confused. If I use `python C:\tmp\git\enigma\blah.py` then it works ok.

Still checking why this should matter.... never mind, it's not a Python thing.

Comment: That is pretty strange behavior.

Comment: Are there any more details you can provide? e.g. the working directory manipulation>

Comment: Trying to see if there are any relevant details. I'm adding lots of print statements :/

Comment: The subprocess program it executes is `yarn` if that makes any difference...

Comment: UGH, it looks like the issue is with case-sensitivity; I'll update my description.

Comment: Unrelated issue not relevant to Python.